# Not Getting Push noitification using parse.com in android

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, push

I have made an android demo,in that i have implemented parse push notification,I have followed the step as per told,But I am not getting any notification on the device,Please help me what is wrong in this code,My code is as below:
**application.java**

```
Parse.initialize(this, "My app_id",
                "Client_key");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, QuestionOFDayActivity.class);
            // PushService.unsubscribe(getApplicationContext(), "MQOD");

            PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), "MQOD",
                    QuestionOFDayActivity.class);
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            String message = "Client message";
            push.setChannel("Channel Name");
            push.setMessage(message);
            push.sendInBackground();
```

**manifest.xml**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.medicineqod.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.medicineqod.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.medicineqod.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="droidparts_dependency_provider"
            android:value=".DependencyProvider" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.QuestionOFDayActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.FavouriteQuestionActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.PastQuestionActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.medicineqod.activity.MyPerformanceActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.medicineqod" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

but have to enabled client push??
if not goto to your parse dashboard and goto settings and click push notifications, there, you will see CLIENT PUSH ENABLED? Off, turn it on and you will be done..
well then i think one: Since this is parse you should delete all recievers except parse,parse
will automatically send it wihout the aid of the gcm reciever.. it should be like this

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

also does it show on the dashboard that it has been sent?
Two: the setchannel input in your case should receive "MQOD" and you can sent push to yourself.. 
Try and.. let me know

Comment: Yes,Thank you,I have enabled it,Actually i am confused as i get notifications very well when i am sending it "manually" from parse.com but i want it automatically(not on click of send button from parse website). got my doubt?